# MouseEvent not working in chart Area

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

[image: Chart]

I am writing a program that gives a quick visual display of mySQL data, I would like to add a feature that gives the coordinates of the mouse location when the mouse is on the chart.

Problem is, ALL my mouse events ONLY work outside the chart area in red, anytime I try a mouse event such as: move/click/rightclick/scroll on the chart area itself (red area), it does not work.

Here is a simple piece of test code that I used:

```
    void chart1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
          MessageBox.Show("");
    }
```

Clicking displays a message box only if clicked OUTSIDE the chart area (i.e. below the red box in the picure), however while the mouse is over the chart, nothing happens.

Comment: In your ChartAreas collection, how many chart areas do you have?

Comment: In the code behind of your Form Designer, is the MouseClick event properly hooked up like this: this.chart1.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.chart1_MouseClick);

Comment: jstreet - just one chart

Comment: I don't mean multiple charts, i mean multiple "ChartAreas" within the same chart, if you know what i mean. In a chart , the ChartArea property is a collection.

Comment: jstreet - yes that worked!! thanks, I thought .focus() would solve the issue of making the mouse events focus on the chart. but the command you gave did the trick

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to add this line of code in the Form Designer:

(thanks to comment by jstreet for letting me know)

```
this.chart1.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.chart1_MouseClick);
```